# Application to run both on azure and on premises

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have application based on azure app service

this application use worker role and azure storage and azure sql database

i have recent requirement to allow my application to work on premises

how i can do that and what is the alternative to the above technology without using azure stack

Answer (score 0):

Your question or scenario is not very clear, however based on my understanding you’re intending to connect Azure App Service to have on premise connectivity. If this is the case, you have the following options and you can choose the feature that best works for your requirement. By default, App Service hosted apps are directly internet accessible and can only reach internet hosted endpoints. However, if you need to control the inbound and outbound network traffic ( I believe this is your case):

1 - **Hybrid Connections** can connect Azure App Service Web Apps to on-premises resources that use a static TCP port. Supported resources include Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, HTTP Web APIs, Mobile Services, and most custom Web Services. For more details on Hybrid Connection, see - https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#app-service-hybrid-connection-benefits

2 - **VNET integration with VPN Gateway**- Apps can access on-premises resources by integrating with VNets that have site-to-site connections. If you are using the gateway required VNet Integration, you need to update your on-premises VPN gateway routes with your point-to-site address blocks. For this, you either need VNet to on-premises using ExpressRoute or a site-to-site VPN.  For more details on the use-case, checkout the document – 
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

**3 - ASE** – For Apps that need to access corporate resources such as internal databases and web services. If you deploy the ASE in a virtual network that has a VPN connection to the on-premises network, the apps in the ASE can access the on-premises resources. 
If you want to access resources like SQL or Storage over service endpoints, enable service endpoints on the ASE subnet. If you want to access resources in the VNet, there is no additional configuration required. If you want to access resources across ExpressRoute, you are already in the VNet and do not need to configure anything on the ASE or the apps inside it. For additional details on this, checkout the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro

Kindly refer this is great document to start with - https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking-features -is intended to help customers determine what feature should be used based on some example use cases.